# Need help determining the convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Lately I was struggling whilst studying for my Calculus exam with determining the convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\arcsin\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}}{n}$$

Any help or explanation how to solve it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: There are many ways you might add context to a bare problem statement like this.  Perhaps you've noticed something about the behavior of the terms in the sequence?  It is expected that you will have digested the meaning of the problem statement before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fact that $\arcsin x\sim x$ when $x\to 0$. And absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: The inverse sine is odd (i.e. $\arcsin(-x) = -\arcsin{x}$) and increasing (i.e., if $x > y$, then $\arcsin{x} > \arcsin{y}$. These two criteria should be strongly suggestive of which of the standard convergence tests to use.

Bonus question (which sometimes comes packaged with these types of questions): determine if the series is absolutely convergent. (For this one, you'll want to use the limit comparison test.)

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\arcsin \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2 n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^n\frac{\arcsin \frac{1}{2 n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^na_n,$$
where $a_n:=\frac{\arcsin \frac{1}{2 n+1}}{n}$. Note that $(a_n)$ is positive, decreasing (because $\arcsin$ is) and converges to $0$.

By the alternating series test, the series converges.